# Intente subir mi pagina web con github pages pero me salio un error

Tags: html, css, github

Al usar el hosting de github para subir mi pagina web,me salio el error 404. Mi pagina tiene el index.html ,css e imagenes.todo

Answer (score 0):

Las paginas en GitHub pages pueden demorar hasta 24 horas en actualizarse despues de hacer un commit , si en el proyecto tienes un archivo index.html no deberia fallar , solo tienes que esperar.
Saludos